# How can I solve a Volterra (Fredholm?) integral equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, integral

I'm talking about Volterra integral equations of second order:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/8/8/a/88a1099a41f2ae451f427ab52ba7888d.png]

In my case `g` is an ugly integral also between `a` and `x`, also `a=0` (for both `g` and the integral above). `K` is equal to 1.

I found some information about Fredholm equations, but they are not exactly the same (fixed intervals, they don't have `x` on the integral sign), I wonder if maybe I can reconduct my analysis to a Fredholm equation? And if so, how can I solve it in Matlab?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. I edited it to include the picture and I tried to make it easier to understand, but you may want to check my edit.

Comment: thanks @David, I corrected a few things but your edit was perfect. why doesn't it make sense? given g,a,and K how would you find f?

Comment: @user3149593 , write your integral equation in its complete form.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm f(x)=10x+int(between 0-x) f(s)ds  should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Volterra equation of the second kind, and in the case when the kernel takes the form k(x-t) it can be solved  an operational way(method).

Since your task is not unique, will be convenient to use a ready solution:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49721-volterra-integral-equations-solver
Solve your equation (if I understood correctly problem statement):

```
isolve(1,10*x,1)

ans =

10*exp(x) - 10
```

Will check the correctness of the solution by substituting in the source:

```
10*x + int(y,0,x)

ans =

10*exp(x) - 10
```

Solved correctly.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: wow, reading the code inside isolve() I realized that a costant kernel (in my case K=1) can be seen as a convolutionary one...your answer solved my issue, even if now I wonder how could I solve a volterra equation of the second kind that has a generic kernel (with no assumptions on his form).